# VB.Net WebBrowser searching on bing rather than Google

Tags: vb.net, bing

so as the title says, everytime I search something on my WebBrowser, it searches it on Bing, when in the code it clearly tells it to search on GOOGLE, there is no code whatsoever that involves the word bing.

Const GOOGLE_SEARCH As String = "http://www.google.com/search?q="

CType(TabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls.Item(0), WebBrowser).Navigate(GOOGLE_SEARCH + urlBox.Text)

And this happens when there is no website displayed other than "about:blank"

What could be the cause of this? Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Nevermind, I fixed this. Apparently adding the same line of code twice makes it search on bing......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be encoding the text that you are appending to the query string. You can use the [UrlEncode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zttxte6w(v=vs.110).aspx) method on the HttpServerUtility to do this.

In your specific example:

```
CType(TabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls.Item(0), WebBrowser).Navigate(GOOGLE_SEARCH + HttpServerUtility.UrlEncode(urlBox.Text))
```

Comment: Thank you for the tip! So as written on the MSDN website, this will ensure that all browsers, so in this case, my browser submits the search query properly, right?
Edit: It gave me an error saying that HttpServerUtility" is not declared, am I supposed to create a class for it?

Comment: You need to add a reference to the System.Web assembly. If you have that reference, you can fully qualify the method call as System.Web.HttpServerUtility.UrlEncode.